# Shopify Variant Featured Image Swatches

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

I am adapting a theme which uses colour swatches to use the variant image.

The problem I am having is that is is displaying the same variant image repeated rather than one for each of the colours available.

```
{%- liquid
                assign color_file_name = value | handle | append: '.' | append: swatch_file_extension
                assign color_image = color_file_name | file_img_url: '50x50' | prepend: 'https:' | split: '?' | first
                assign color_swatch_fallback = value | split: ' ' | last | handle
              -%}
              <label
                for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.name }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                class="color__swatch color__swatch--{{ block.settings.swatch_type }}"
                style="--swatch-background-image: url({% for variant in product.variants %}{{ variant.image | img_url: 'small' }}{% endfor %}); height:50px; width:50px;"
                title="{{ value | escape }}"
              ><span class="color__swatch-dot"></span>
              </label>
```

[preview screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8hM2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`{%- if is_color -%} {%- liquid assign color_file_name = value | handle | append: '.' | append: swatch_file_extension assign custom_variant = product.variants[forloop.index0] if custom_variant.featured_image assign color_image = custom_variant.featured_image | img_url: '50x50' | split: '?' | first assign product_url = custom_variant.url else assign color_image = color_file_name | file_img_url: '50x50' | prepend: 'https:' | split: '?' | first endif assign color_swatch_fallback = value | split: ' ' | last | handle -%} <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.name }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="color__swatch color__swatch--{{ block.settings.swatch_type }}" style="--swatch-background-color: {{ color_swatch_fallback }};{% if color_image != blank %} --swatch-background-image: url({{ color_image }});{% endif %}" title="{{ value | escape }}" > <span class="color__swatch-dot"></span> </label> {%- else -%} <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.name }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"> {{ value }} </label> {%- endif -%}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).